# NotificationCompat.Builder is giving Error :Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

I wrote a code in a class to notify me using the notificationCompat.Builder and it's giving me this error, It's telling me that I've done something before OnCreate(), Inside MainActivity I'm declaring another class in order to Inherit CountDownTimer class and inside the OnFinished () method I wrote this small code and it's giving me an Error. Can anyone help me ? I believe using this.activity is causing the problem but I don't know a workaround for this  :

```
public NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
 MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
 NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
 public override void OnFinish() 
 { 
     Toast.MakeText(Application.Context ,"Finished",ToastLength.Short).Show();
      builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.activity, CHANNEL_ID).SetAutoCancel(true)
    .SetContentTitle("CountDownTimer !!")
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_star_black_48dp)
    .SetContentText($" Stopped"); //  display.
      notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this.activity);   Error  //  Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'System services not available to Activities...
     notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
 }
```

Comment: you can't just create a new instance of `MainActivity`, you need to use a reference to your App's existing `MainActivity`

Comment: If I use the "this " keyword I get  ,Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TimerApp_Test.MainActivity.CountDown1' to 'Android.Content.Context' ?? ,that is again my CountDown1 class is inside MainActivity

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about how to get a reference to the current Activity

Comment: Thanks I  created a Context and passed it  **this** in my Oncreate () , then I just used the object in another class !

Comment: You can put your answer below if that worked for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code is just to illustrate Reference to current Activity  :

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    
    static Context context;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        context = this; 
    
    }

    public class CountDown1 : CountDownTimer 
    {
         
        public NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
         
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

       
        public override void OnFinish() 
        { 
            Toast.MakeText(Application.Context ,"Finished",ToastLength.Short).Show();
             builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID).SetAutoCancel(true)
           .SetContentTitle("CountDownTimer !!")
           .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ic_star_black_48dp)
           .SetContentText($" Stopped"); // the message to display.

             notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(context);// Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: 'System services not available to Activities before onCreate()'
            notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());

        }
        
    }
    
}
```

}